# Regex expression not returning anything after adding check for precision in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, validation, precision

im just trying to figure out why my input is not outputting anything after I added the precision check in my regex. It simply will not show anything in the input field after the precision check is added into the regex. I have looked for examples to dynamically render the precision value and it seems like it is something similar to what I have implemented in my code:

```
const handleAssetAmountFormat = (value) => {
    if (value) {
        const precision = transactionType === TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY ? selectedBaseCurrencyObj.precision.cost : selectedBaseCurrencyObj.precision.amount;
        const regex = new RegExp(`/^\d+\.?\d${precision}/`);
        const result = value.match(regex);
        if (result) {
            return result[0];
        }
    }
    return '';
};



const handleAssetAmount = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const formattedAmount = handleAssetAmountFormat(value);
    setFromCurrencyAmount(formattedAmount);
  };
```

Anyone able to figure out what's going on here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `precision` a string and what are the values that `precision` can be? Can you give example valid and invalid inputs?

Comment: @IainShelvington precision is a number of type Number. And the number will change depending on the asset and type of the order in my app. 

In this case, precision.cost is 2 and precision.amount is 6. So if it is a buy transaction, a valid input would be something like 5.05 for a 'buy' and maybe something like 5.055555 for a sell side

Comment: Precision is the maximum allowed precision? Would 5.0555 for a sell be valid?

Comment: @IainShelvington In my case, precision should be the amount of 0s after decimal that must be there. So that will be an invalid sell in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things are wrong:

1. You use a string literal, yet you use slashes, they should not be
   there.
2. You should use double escape to escape your control characters.
3. You should add an extra pair of `{ }` around the precision to act as
   a quantifier.

This result in this regex, that should work:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`^\\d+\\.?\\d{${precision}}`);
```

Alternatively you could use `String.Raw`. Then you don't have to double escape. That would be:

```
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`^\d+\.?\d{${precision}}`);
```

Comment: Awesome. This seems to be headed in the right direction. Is there anyway I can append a decimal to the input as well with this method? @Poul Bak

Comment: I don't understand, you can use like: `45.566` as input.

Comment: Actually you are right about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to check but as far as I can tell normally a re starts with ^(caret) symbol and ends with an $ symbol but you are using a /(escape) character try using the escape characters outside of parentheses.